# Using scaled equations to go from $\rho u_{tt}(x, t) + Ek^2u_{xxxx}(x, t) = 0$ to $v_{\tau \tau} + Jv_{\zeta \zeta \zeta \zeta} = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I am given the partial differential equation $\rho u_{tt}(x, t) + Ek^2u_{xxxx}(x, t) = 0$ for modelling a beam/rod, where

$0 < x < l$, where $l$ is the length of the rod,
$u(0, t) = a \sin(\omega t)$,
$u_x(0, t) = 0$,
$u_{xx}(l, t) = 0$,
$u_{xxx}(l ,t) = 0$.

I am then provided with the scaled equations

$$x = l \zeta, \ \ \ \tau = \omega t, \ \ \ u = av,$$

and told that we therefore have that

$$v_{\tau \tau} + Jv_{\zeta \zeta \zeta \zeta} = 0,$$

where $J = \dfrac{E k^2}{\rho \omega^2 l^4}$, where $E$ is Young's modulus, $k$ is the radius of gyration, $\rho$ is the density, $\omega$ is the frequency, and $l$ is the length of the rod.

However, there is no explanation for how the scaled equations are used to go from $\rho u_{tt}(x, t) + Ek^2u_{xxxx}(x, t) = 0$ to $v_{\tau \tau} + Jv_{\zeta \zeta \zeta \zeta} = 0$. And this is the first exposure to such material, so there is no basis for expecting someone to know what happened here. I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to explain this.

Comment: It is just the chain rule applied to $$u(x,t) \to av(\zeta(x), \tau(t))$$ so that \begin{align} u_{t} &\to a v_{\tau} \tau_{t} = a \omega v_{\tau} \\ u_{x} &\to a v_{\zeta} \zeta_{x} = \frac{a v_{\zeta}}{l} \end{align} etc.

Comment: @mattos How do we extend the chain rule to account for the 2nd/4th derivative?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'extend the chain rule'. You just need to keep computing derivatives \begin{align} u_{xx} &\to \left( \frac{a v_{\zeta}}{l} \right)_{x} \\ &= \frac{a}{l} v_{\zeta \zeta} \zeta_{x} \\ &= \frac{a v_{\zeta \zeta}}{l^{2}} \\ u_{xxx} &\to \left( \frac{a v_{\zeta \zeta}}{l^{2}} \right)_{x} \\ &= \frac{a}{l^{2}} v_{\zeta \zeta \zeta} \zeta_{x} \\ &= \frac{a v_{\zeta \zeta \zeta}}{l^{3}} \end{align} etc.